# setting ImageViews src in a ListView

Tags: android

i started android development about a week ago and i made a small application with listview  fetching the data for it from a xml file an a remote server where i get a (name, date, details, image url) everything works fine except for the imageview where it shows nothing.
here is the code i used:

```
public class ActivityListViewActivity extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    XMLParser parse = new XMLParser(); 
    //this is where i get my data from the xml file
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> newsList = parse.StartParsing();

    ListAdapter adaptor = new SimpleAdapter(this, newsList, R.layout.list_item
            , new String[] {"name", "description", "date", "details", "image"},     new int[] {
            R.id.name, R.id.description, R.id.date, R.id.details, R.id.image});

    this.setListAdapter(adaptor);
```

Comment: Have you gone through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012

Comment: Loading image from URL or else?

Comment: If loading images from URL then agree with the example @VivekKalkur has mentioned.

Comment: yes the xml data for the images are links, but i don't get the example

Answer (score 0):

Refer following link.
use-  4. Tutorial: ListActivity with own layout
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

You can Implementing your own adapter also.Examples are available in above link.

Comment: thats the same as my code, the problem is that the images won't show